# requirejs config setting with expire cache

Tags: caching, requirejs, config, minify

I'm using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

I need to set the javascript(even css file) cache with expiration(max-age)

I know there's is the config **urlArg**

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=v" +  VERSION    
});
```

In this way, I have to change the value VERSION ***manually*** every single modification

**Can I config it with *automatically* change after modification or expiration time?**

*Besides using Date() Time because it only suitable for development state*

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by dynamic generate urlArgs

https://github.com/huei90/requirejs-cache